# Не пишет ошибку PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, авторизация, переменные, регистрация

При вбивании в input существующего имени не пишит ошибку ВЫБРАННОЕ ИМЯ УЖЕ ЗАНЯТО, а всё остальное работает. В чём может быть глюк?

```
function checkRegUser($newLogin, $newName) {
    global $mysqli;//переменная общего подключения к бд
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = '$newLogin' AND name = '$newName'";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
    $a = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    return $a;
}
if(isset($_POST['newReg'])) {
    $newLogin = $_POST['newLogin'];
    $newName = $_POST['newName'];
    $newPass = $_POST['newPass'];
    
    $checkRegUser = checkRegUser($newLogin, $newName);
    if($checkRegUser['login'] == $newLogin) {$errors = "<p>Выбранный логин уже занят</p>";}
    if($checkRegUser['name'] == $newName) {$errors = "<p>Выбранное имя уже занято</p>";}
    if(empty($_POST['newLogin'])) {$errors = "<p>Вы не ввели логин</p>";}
    if(empty($_POST['newName'])) {$errors = "<p>Вы не ввели имя</p>";}
    if(empty($_POST['newPass'])) {$errors = "<p>Вы не ввели пароль</p>";}
}



<form action="" method="post">
                        <input type="text" name="newLogin" placeholder="Введите логин">
                        <br>
                        <input type="text" name="newName" placeholder="Введите имя">
                        <br>
                        <input type="password" name="newPass" placeholder="Введите пароль">
                        <br>
<?=$errors?>
                        <button type="submit" name="newReg">Регистрация</button>
                        <br>
</form>
```

Comment: Ты  уверен что результат возвращается в $result корректный, мне кажется login = '$newLogin'  '$newName' кавычки одинарные там не нужны.

Comment: послушай, зачем ты твообще регистрацию делаешь, если любой кто захочет сможет без всякого пароля зайти?

Comment: @Ипатьев смысле зачем??? Ты задал вопрос глядя на этот кусок кода или что? Дак это только 1/10 от всего кода регистрации. Если честно не понял твой вопрос.

Comment: ну какая разница, 1/10 или 1/100? Все равно, так как ты пишешь запросы -любой дурак зайдет без регистрации

Comment: @Ипатьев ты про то, что они неподготовленные?

Comment: @АлександрИнженер без кавычек вылезла ошибка **Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND name =' at line 1 in **

Comment: $sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = $newLogin AND name = $newName'; попробуй так, что прийдет в  ответ от сервера

Comment: я про то что они не подготовленные

Comment: что приходит в $a после того запроса, что я написал последним...

Comment: @АлександрИнженер Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Unknown column '$newLogin' in 'where clause' in...........................с кавычками всё работает как изначально

Comment: на запрос свой посмотри

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ именно на данный вопрос заключался в замене оператора `AND` в sql-запросе на `OR`.

Comment: а зачем ты выбрал правильным ответ который вообще не при чем? надо было свой ответ выбирать

Comment: Ты мне опять репу минусал?

Comment: да я. если примешь свой ответ то минус уберу

Comment: через 2 дня только можно

Comment: @ARTISUC ответ не очевиден, ибо твой код при введённых одинаковых login и name покажет только последнюю ошибку из всех твоих перечисленных $errors.

Поэтому озвучил все решения и в том числе в группировке всех ошибок по запросу, и их представил тебе + твой запрос можно использовать как с AND так и с OR, всё зависит от индивидуальных условий.

Ставьте задачу намного корректнее в следующий раз, если хотите получить грамотный ответ от людей, не вовлечённых в ваш проект, не знающих особенность вашего кода. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Новичкам пригодится:

Сначала проанализируй достоверность получения данных и вот подсказки

1. Напиши

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($checkRegUser);
echo '</pre>';
```

после  `$checkRegUser = checkRegUser($newLogin, $newName);`

кавычки в коде замени у меня, если будешь копипастить

2. Заполни поля и нажми кнопку Регистрация
3. Посмотри есть ли в массиве заполненный или вообще хотя бы существующий 'name'. А массив отобразится тут же на экране из-за введённого кода print_r
4. Если 'name' нет, значит из базы не дёргает данные и смотри в стороны получения данных из mysql

У тебя либо 'name' не прилетает в ответном массиве, либо ‘name' пустой, либо с кодировкой что-то

Спасение для первоначального анализа

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($checkRegUser);
echo '</pre>';
```

ещё есть

```
var_export($checkRegUser);
```

И дальше ты сможешь понять что не так с ‘name’ в массиве, который возвращается из базы данных

Если данных нет, от укажите четвёртым параметром в mysqli-connect() название базы данных
[php.net function.mysqli-connect.php](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php)

**Ответ на вопрос:**

Добавляем
`$errors = "";`
перед `if(isset($_POST['newReg'])) {`
и правим в такой вид каждый `$errors .=`

И имеем:

```
$errors = "";
if(isset($_POST['newReg'])) {
    $newLogin = $_POST['newLogin'];
    $newName = $_POST['newName'];
    $newPass = $_POST['newPass'];
    
    $checkRegUser = checkRegUser($newLogin, $newName);
    if($checkRegUser['login'] == $newLogin) {$errors .= "<p>Выбранный логин уже занят</p>";}
    if($checkRegUser['name'] == $newName) {$errors .= "<p>Выбранное имя уже занято</p>";}
    if(empty($_POST['newLogin'])) {$errors .= "<p>Вы не ввели логин</p>";}
    if(empty($_POST['newName'])) {$errors .= "<p>Вы не ввели имя</p>";}
    if(empty($_POST['newPass'])) {$errors .= "<p>Вы не ввели пароль</p>";}
}
```

У тебя всегда в конце выводился крайний $errors, так как он перезаписывал собой остальные. А необходимо либо складывать их в массив, либо конкатенацию производить, что я привёл в примере.

С массивом было бы как

```
$errors = [];
$errors[] = "<p>text</p>";
$errors[] = "<p>text</p>";
```

Comment: я тебе и так могу сказать что в $checkRegUser пусто

Comment: @Ипатьев подскажи тогда свой вариант

Comment: @ARTISUC надо указывать название базы данных четвёртым параметром в подключении [php.net -> mysqli-connect](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php)

Comment: ну это уже совсем пальцем в небо. Если не указать название базы данных, то будет не пустой массив, а ошибка

Comment: @ARTISUC добавил ответ для тебя выше в развёрнутом виде

Comment: @ARTISUC не надо замусоривать сайт принимая ответы которые не отвечают на вопрос